# EntityException was unhandled by User code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, sql-server-2008

I am using `Parallel.Foreach()` loop having certain code that is accessing database to fetch  data. But the code is throwing exception "`EntityException was unhandled by User code`".

Since there is lot of data to be processed so I am using `Parallel.ForEach` instead of foreach(timeout in case of foreach loop).

I am new to this field need your suggestion or any other alternative to avoid timeout.

Comment: You have a bug. Take a look at the thrown EntityException and see why it's thrown.

Comment: have you got further exception details?

Comment: when the control of loop reaches the line where database is read. it gives following exception

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.